# How add new row to existing txt file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, numbers, export-to-csv

I want to insert a new row to a text file using jupyter notebook.

````
25.650  166.965 431.000 12.000  67.000
50.190  231.984 801.000 20.000  98.000
77.840  103.143 244.000 9.000   49.000
82.967  82.682  544.000 15.000  71.000```

Data looks like this, i want to insert column names to the top of the these data and save it in a new csv file
````

Comment: Please read [the docs of the `open` function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @JohnGordon You suggestion would put the column names at the bottom of the file rather than the top.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Pandas to read the csv file as a dataframe, add the columns names, and then save back as a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "your_file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
df.columns = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5']
df.to_csv(filename)
```

Using the `csv` module is a bit more complicated.  Create a new file, write the column names, and then write each row read from the original file.

```
import csv

new_filename = 'your_new_file.csv'
column_names = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_4', 'col_5']
with open(filename, 'r') as infile, open(new_filename, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(column_names)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of being in the Jupyter ecosystem, and simply pre-pend your data file using a shell command while in the notebook. (I am assuming your data columns are tab separated.) In a cell in your notebook, execute the following, replacing `data.tsv` with your file's name and add the real column names for the placeholders:

```
!echo -e "col_1\tcol_2\tcol_3\tcol_4\tcol_5\n$(cat data.tsv)" > data.tsv
```

If you are instead actually using a comma-separated file, use commas where I put `\t`, which adds tabs. Likewise, if the data are just whitespace-separated.